# Fetch string data from JSON response retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm working with JSON response which I can get from my server, at the beginning I have to log in at my application so I use such api:

```
@Headers("Content-type: application/json")
    @POST("/v1/login")
    Call<Post> auth(@Body Post body);
```

and also my POJO-class:

```
public class Post {
    @SerializedName("username")
    private String username;
    @SerializedName("password")
    private String password;

    public Post(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername (String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

and after all initialize it at my mainactivity class:

```
public void sendPost() {
        final EditText titleEt = findViewById(R.id.login);
        final EditText bodyEt = findViewById(R.id.password);
        final String a = titleEt.getText().toString().trim();
        final String b = bodyEt.getText().toString().trim();

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://server/")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        //retrofit.create(APIService.class);

        mAPIService.auth(new Post(a, b)).enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Post> call, @NonNull Response<Post> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Post submitted to API.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SecondScreen.class);
                    findViewById(R.id.btn_submit).getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#1cd000"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    saveData();
                   /* try {
                        String responseString = String.valueOf(response.body());
                        TextView txt = findViewById(R.id.post);
                        txt.setText(responseString);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }*/


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Unable to submit post to API.Error!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    findViewById(R.id.btn_submit).getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Post> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Unable to submit post to API.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

as you can see I commented my trying to fetch some data from JSON response, in general, I would like to get my access token from the response and I also wouldn't like to create some classes for fetching if it is possible, because I have already initialized my retrofit at my MainActivity class. After logging in a can get my received and sent messages in JSON too, but I would like to insert this data into the simple listview. So I hope that somebody at this forum will help me with my problem. Sorry for my maybe bad English.

Comment: My eyes looked for a stack trace. Moreover, the problem is not quite clear to me.

Comment: Are you asking about stack trace of my tryings? Because I can't fetch any string data from my json responce))

Comment: You have to get response.body() as String and create JSONObject or JsonObject with this string, then you can take fields from JSON as usual. I don't remember is it body().toString() or body().string() method

Comment: as per your request , your response returns you a `Post` type json object and to get these variables you have to do `response.body.getUsername()/getPassword()`...

Comment: So as I understood from all your comments I can't get from my responce my access_token)))

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that each Retrofit request is **asynchronous**, that means, it will eventually be executed while your application runs. You should  use *RxJava* to help you with that, since you should use to **observe** the data you need to get from your **API**.

**Important Note**: Also updating UI in your response from retrofit might trigger exceptions due to not running in Main Thread.

Some useful links to implement what you need :

https://www.toptal.com/android/functional-reactive-android-rxjava

https://www.journaldev.com/20433/android-rxjava-retrofit

https://medium.com/3xplore/handling-api-calls-using-retrofit-2-and-rxjava-2-1871c891b6ae